# Computing outer measure

Tags: measure-theory

Compute $m^*(\{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n:n\in N\})$

I'm fairly new to outer measures and having trouble using the definition of an outer measure to compute this. Thank you for any help!

Comment: What would be your guess? This is a countable set. What would the outer Lebesgue measure of **any** countable set be?

Comment: if you know $m^{*}(\mathbb{Q})=0$ you may use it because $$\{\left ( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right )^n| n \in \mathbb{N} \} \subset \mathbb{Q}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E=\{x_i\}$ be an indexation for the numerable set $E$, then $E=\bigcup \{x_n\}$. Since $m^*(\{x_n\})=0$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (is easy to see that a single point set has outer measure $0$), then by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382798/outer-measure-sequence-of-subsets-proof) $m^*(E)=0$.