# Outer measure, sequence of subsets proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory

Let $I_o=[a,b]$ be a fixed interval and let $A$ be a subset of $I_o$. Show that if $\{A_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is a sequence of subsets of $I_o$ such that $m^*(A_n)=0$ for every $n \in N$ then

$m^*(\bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} {A_n})=0$.

I'm struggling with this proof and looking for some direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$0\leq m^*(\bigcup {A_n})\leq \sum m^*(A_n)=\sum0=0$$

By $\sigma$-subadditivity of outer measure.